# Is it fine if I would use ini_set("memory_limit",-1); in my php file

Tags: php, xampp

I am exporting data from MySQL database table to an Excel file. But exporting large amounts of data shows a memory limit error.

I have set memory limit in my `php.ini` file to 1024M and its working fine now since its having 300,000 records/rows now.

But this count will keep growing so I used following code in my PHP file. But I am not sure if its right to do or not. I hope it won't affect any of my functionalities.

```
ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
```

Here is the code I am using to export data from an Excel database:

```
ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
if (isset($_POST["export"])) {

    $query_discount = "SELECT  * FROM tb_discount";
$productResult1 = mysql_query($query_discount, $con);

    $filename_discount = "Discount_data_report.xls";
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename_discount\"");
    $isPrintHeader_discount = false;
    if (! empty($productResult1)) {
         while ($row_discount = mysql_fetch_assoc($productResult1)) {

            if (! $isPrintHeader_discount) {
                echo implode("\t", array_keys($row_discount)) . "\n";
                $isPrintHeader_discount = true;
            }
            echo implode("\t", array_values($row_discount)) . "\n";
        }
    }
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Do not increase PHP `memory_limit` unless you really have to and only do it in the code section or file that needs that limit.

In general this all depends on your code and PHP scripts are not memory hogs.

PHP scripts just use memory as scripts are run. So if this is on an Apache server, if you blanketly just remove  `memory_limit` block, then anyone using your website can potentially DDoS your site by flooding it with requests that will just arbitrarily fill the RAM on your server until the site is unusable. Even if you are using this script from the command line—meaning you yourself run it when needed—this is considered bad practice.

But there is a solution that can work.

Simply add that `ini_set("memory_limit",-1);` directive *only* to the script or chunk of code that absolutely needs it.

So if your Excel export code runs in one single, specific file, just add that `ini_set("memory_limit",-1);` to that file. Or if you have more complex code that the Excel export is a part of, it’s best to just put that `ini_set("memory_limit",-1);` in the code area that handles the export *only* and not in the rest of the code.

So of you have a function or method that handles the export, just place that `ini_set("memory_limit",-1);` in that function or method. Or perhaps you have an `if` conditional for the export? Just then place that `ini_set("memory_limit",-1);` in the `if` conditional area.

At the end of the day, things like `memory_limit` are set for a reason; they are not your enemy. Always adjust them in a way that allows them to have a limit and *only* lift that limit if a task or condition absolutely requires it.

So in the case of your example code, I would recommend changing these two lines from this:

```
ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
if (isset($_POST["export"])) {
```

To this:

```
if (isset($_POST["export"])) {
    ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
```

That way you are only every removing the `memory_limit` restriction when you are clearly and definitely doing an export.

And past any of that…

### Your code has clear scalability issues.

#### Refactor your code so it can properly scale without reaching memory limits.

Without seeing your code, it seems like you are making only blanket MySQL query without an `OFFSET` or `LIMIT` and that is causing you issues. Instead, I would record you refactor your code to use `OFFSET` or `LIMIT` in the MySQL code and then append the results to your exported Excel file. This would allow you to not worry about PHP memory limit and allows you to scale the code better.

Something like a `foreach` PHP loop that adjusts the `OFFSET` or `LIMIT` on a set basis of—let’s say—1,000 records per loop that then appends data to that Excel file. This is the better, scalable and more reliable long-term solution.